# Mongoexport strict json load in Spark

Tags: json, mongodb, apache-spark, mongoexport

I have a process that exports data from a mongodb using `mongoexport`.
As the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#considerations) mentions all json  output is in **Strict** mode

This means data will look like this:

```
"{amount":{"$numberLong":"3"},"count":{"$numberLong":"245"}}
```

Where as my Scala case class is defined as:

```
case class MongoData(amount: Long, count: Long)
```

Reading the data will of course fail like this:

```
spark
      .read
      .json(inputPath)
      .as[MongoData]
```

Is there a way to either export from mongo without the strict mode or to import the json in Scala without manually restructuring each field to the appropriate structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm now using this as solution. but it feels somewhat hacky.

```
case class DataFrameExtended(dataFrame: DataFrame) {

   def undoMongoStrict(): DataFrame = {
    val numberLongType = StructType(List(StructField("$numberLong", StringType, true))) 

    def restructure(fields: Array[StructField], nesting: List[String] = Nil): List[Column] = {
      fields.flatMap(field => {
        val fieldPath = nesting :+ field.name
        val fieldPathStr = fieldPath.mkString(".")
        field.dataType match {
          case dt: StructType if dt == numberLongType =>
            Some(col(s"$fieldPathStr.$$numberLong").cast(LongType).as(field.name))
          case dt: StructType =>
            Some(struct(restructure(dt.fields, fieldPath): _*).as(field.name))
          case _ => Some(col(fieldPathStr).as(field.name))
          //              case dt:ArrayType => //@todo handle other DataTypes Array??
        }
      })
    }.toList


    dataFrame.select(restructure(dataFrame.schema.fields): _*)
  }
}

implicit def dataFrameExtended(df: DataFrame): DataFrameExtended = {
  DataFrameExtended(df)
}

spark
  .read
  .json(inputPath)
  .undoMongoStrict()
```

Comment: `mongoexport` is designed to produce json that can be roundtripped. A requirement for that is that it doesn't lose type information. I think your solution works well given the nature of the input.

Comment: are there other open source (cli) tools that allow exporting from mongo without the strict option?

Comment: Not currently, however as a result of [DRIVERS-342](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DRIVERS-342) a relaxed style Json spec is in the process of being ratified. Once set, all supported drivers will update and add the new relaxed setting. I'm not sure if there are current plans for the server to support it as well.